# Setting grails link id using javascript

Tags: jquery, grails, hyperlink

I am trying to set the id on a grails link, dynamically, using javascript. Is that even possible?

```
<g:link controller:"patient" action:"show" id:"patient0-id"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var id = 20;
   $("#patient0-id").attr("id", id);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible since the Grails tag is processed server-side (before the page is rendered by the client) and JQuery/Javascript is processed client-side in the browser after the Grails tag has already been processed by the server. Thus, you can't use JQuery/Javascript to effect the Grails tag.

However, you could do something like this:

```
<a id="someLink" href="#">Something</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var baseUrl = "${createLink(controller: 'someThing', action: 'someAction'}";
  var id = 1234;
  $("#someLink").attr("href", baseUrl+"/"+id);
</script>
```

Comment: This is the correct approach; however, be sure you formulate the final link URL according to your URLMappings, if you have changed them from the Grails defaults.